# How can I fix Sportsdevil add-on in XBMC running on Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: xbmc

Sportsdevil (video add-on for live sports) seems not be working in XBMC across other operating system as well, the issue being "No stream available", but while there are tutorials about how to fix this problem in XBMC running in Windows, Android and Mac OS, I could not find any for Ubuntu. 
In Windows there is a directory called *app data* where programs like XBMC store all their data and in that directory some downloaded fix files must be pasted and so on...
I read that Ubuntu does not realy have an *app data* equivalent.
So, does anybody know how to address this issue with Sportsdevil ?
Let me explain more...
The zip file to fix Sportsdevil can be downloaded and after extracting it, the folder named *catchers* and the folder named *modules*, must be copied where XBMC stores all its data in app data directory. That is the first step BUT this tutorial is for Windows OS.

PS: I'm fairly new to Linux OS, so if any of you have instructions, please explain them as much as possible in layman terms aka tutorial for stupids. LOL
Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest equivalent to `AppData` would be the (hidden) `.config` in your home directory. You'll find this contains folders with the settings for most commonly used applications.

However, a number of applications like `XBMC` create their own directory rather than use this one, so you'll find XBMC's settings, database etc in `$HOME/.xbmc`.

(You can see hidden directories in the file browser with `View->Show Hidden Files`).